# Ada - Empty file

Tags: file-io, ada, is-empty

I'm writing a program in Ada language that creates a WEP keys dictionary for pentesting purposes. Here is the code :

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure CreateWepDict is

    type IntegerTab is array (1..29) of integer;

    -- Initializes the password
    procedure PasswdInit (Passwd : in out IntegerTab; LgPasswd : in Integer) is
    begin
        for i in 1..LgPasswd loop
            Passwd(i) := 0;
        end loop;
    end PasswdInit;

    -- Writes the current password into the dictionary file
    procedure WriteWepDict (PasswdInt : in IntegerTab; LgPasswd : in Integer) is
        PasswdDict : File_Type;
        PasswdStr  : String(1..29);
    begin
        if not Is_Open(PasswdDict) then
            open(PasswdDict,Append_File,"WepDict.txt");
        end if;
        for i in 1..LgPasswd loop
            case PasswdInt(i) is
                when 1 => PasswdStr(i) := '0';
                when 2 => PasswdStr(i) := '1';
                when 3 => PasswdStr(i) := '2';
                when 4 => PasswdStr(i) := '3';
                when 5 => PasswdStr(i) := '4';
                when 6 => PasswdStr(i) := '5';
                when 7 => PasswdStr(i) := '6';
                when 8 => PasswdStr(i) := '7';
                when 9 => PasswdStr(i) := '8';
                when 10 => PasswdStr(i) := '9';
                when 11 => PasswdStr(i) := 'A';
                when 12 => PasswdStr(i) := 'B';
                when 13 => PasswdStr(i) := 'C';
                when 14 => PasswdStr(i) := 'D';
                when 15 => PasswdStr(i) := 'E';
                when 16 => PasswdStr(i) := 'F';
                when others => pragma assert(false);
            end case;
        end loop;
        New_Line(PasswdDict);
        close(PasswdDict);
    end WriteWepDict;

    PasswdDict : File_Type;
    LgPasswd : Integer := 5;
    PassCur : Integer := 1;
    Passwd : IntegerTab;

begin
    -- Creates the dictionary file
    create(PasswdDict,Append_File,"WepDict.txt");
    PasswdInit(Passwd,LgPasswd);
    while LgPasswd <= 29 loop
        if PassCur /= LgPasswd then
            PassCur := PassCur + 1;
        else
            if Passwd(PassCur) /= 16 then
                Passwd(PassCur) := Passwd(PassCur) + 1;
            else
                Passwd(PassCur) := 1;
                if PassCur /= 1 then
                    PassCur := PassCur - 1;
                else
                    LgPasswd := LgPasswd + 1;
                    PasswdInit(Passwd,LgPasswd);
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
        WriteWepDict(Passwd,LgPasswd);
    end loop;

end CreateWepDict;
```

I have a "statement expected" error at "end case" in the WriteWepDict sub-procedure. Could you tell me why?

EDIT : I rewrote the program according to Brian's changes, but now there is another problem : the created file is empty!

Comment: You appear to declare `PasswdDict : File_Type;` twice; perhaps one is hiding the other? Note that if you declare it before the local procedure WriteWepDict, it would be visible to that procedure (if you also removed the second declaration in WriteWepDict)

Comment: If you want us to help figure out what the problem with the rewritten program is, perhaps you should post the rewritten program?  In the original program, you go to all the trouble of setting up `PasswdStr` but then you don't do anything with it.  Is this the case with the new code also?  Did you forget a `Put_Line`?

Comment: Yeah, probably best to revert this question's title and ask a new question with the new code...

Comment: F***! @ajb You're right : I forgot the Put_Line in WriteWepDict!!! I got my head in the clouds!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

a 'pragma' is not an actual valid language statement, it is a compiler directive.  The equivalent of #pragma in C (sort-of).  Change it to raise an exception or print an error message, see if that works.

Comment: The standard approach is to use the `null;` statement (as well as the `pragma`).

Answer (score 0):

This probably shouldn't be an answer but it's a poor fit for a comment:

I would replace the entire Case with a lookup in a constant array...

```
   Lookup : constant array(1 .. 16) of Character := 
                  ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', 
                   '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');

   PasswdStr(i) := Lookup(PasswdInt(i));
```

You could also greatly improve this code by declaring:
`subtype PW_Index is natural range 1 to 29;`

and using it throughout, as the following incomplete code fragments show:
`type IntegerTab is array (PW_Index) of integer;`

```
procedure WriteWepDict (PasswdInt : in IntegerTab; LgPasswd : in PW_Index) is
    PasswdStr  : String(PW_Index);
begin
```

...

```
    LgPasswd : PW_Index := 5;
    PassCur  : PW_Index := 1;

begin
    ...
    loop
        ...
                else
                    exit when LgPasswd = PW_Index'Last;
                    LgPasswd := LgPasswd + 1;
                    PasswdInit(Passwd,LgPasswd);
                end if;
        ...
    end loop;
```

... can you see how rewriting along these lines would give buffer overflows nowhere to hide?

To say nothing of the simplicity of maintenance if you ever change the password length...

The unfamiliar looking loop structure with 'exit when' is arguably preferable to dealing with the otherwise ugly out-of-range value for LgPasswd, which given the above declaration would give a Constraint_Error exception...

Comment: O_o Wow... I wouldn't expect as much optimizations. Thank you for your help, I'm going to try it right now.

Comment: It's not so much about optimisations (a good compiler should translate the Case efficiently), but about trying to make a better (less buggy, more readable, maintainable) program. For example the original While loop will bump LgPasswd up to 30, and pass it to PasswdInit and WriteWepDict before terminating, which might not be what you want! Declaring LgPasswd as PW_Index, that last increment would terminate your program right at the problem with ConstraintError, rather than somewhere else (or in some languages, write off the end of an array)